# How does the last turn of an epoch run in Priests of Ra?

Tags: priests-of-ra

Just bought Priests of Ra and am really enjoying it, but am not quite sure how the final turn of each epoch should be played. The rules state an epoch ends when the final sun is flipped over, so what happens when the second to last sun is flipped over? Does the player with one remaining sun get to keep drawing tiles on his own, and can call "Ra" and bid on them with no-one opposing him? This seems a little odd.

Comment: FYI sometimes there's more than one player left when there's only one sun left to go.

Comment: @ruds How could this happen? Surely the number if only one player has a sun left, by definition they can be the only one remaining?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I've misread the question! I was thinking of the situation when there's only one more space for a Ra tile during the epoch.

Comment: It's a little odd, but an integral part of the game.  I'd also look out for "Grab" or "Simpsons slam dunk", which is a very similar card game (same designer) but played at speed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like yes, I was correct in my original question, the final player gets to keep drawing tiles until the epoch ends, e.g. by the Ra track filling up.

http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/811805/last-person-have-sun-tile

Comment: It's sort of like a game of chicken -- do I take the current set or risk a Ra tile or plague coming up?